# Change body background image with css

Tags: html, css

So I am trying to change my background image, the problem is, as it is on my body, it is also changing on my other web page and I do not want it but I want to keep the same background image. Should I give an id/class to my body on my first page (where I want to hover function)?

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>MakeHappy, One good thought everyday!</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="randomMessages.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MakeHappy.css" />
</head>
<div id="wink" class="imageSwap">
</div>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a id="MakeHappy" href="Main.html">Make Happy</a>
        <a id="Contact" href="#">Contact us</a>
        <a id="Suscribe" href="#">Suscribe</a>
        <a id="Project" href="#">Project</a>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

</body>
```

\

```
<!DOCTYPE Html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="randomMessages.js"></script>
  <title>MakeHappy, One good thought everyday!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MakeHappy.css" />
</head>
<body class="Main">
  <input type="button" onclick="popup()" value="Click to be Happy!">
  <div  id="demo"></div>
</body>
```

\

```
body {
  background-image: url("MakeHappy.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 200px 60px;
  background-size: 900px;
  background-color: black;
}
body:hover{
  background-image: url("MakeHappy2.jpg");
  background-position: 200px 60px;
}
.Main{
  background-size: 100px;
  background-position:top;
}
.imageSwap{
  position:absolute;
  color: yellow;
  padding: 150px;
  bottom: 130px;
  right: 500px
}
#MakeHappy{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 660px;
}
#Contact{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 660px;
  bottom: 10px;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
#Suscribe{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 320px;
  bottom: 300px;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
#Project{
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  right: 360px;
  bottom: 300px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.Main div{
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
}
input{
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 150px;
  left: 625px;
}
```

Comment: In pure html/css, what if you left the site background alone and just added an embedded style tag on your home page with the desired background image and marked it as !important? Would that work for you?

Comment: Try to avoid capitalized ids/classess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give it a class with that specific background, if you only want the hover on lets say your startpage.

```
body {
  background-image: url("MakeHappy.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 200px 60px;
  background-size: 900px;
  background-color: black;
}

.startpage-background:hover{
  background-image: url("MakeHappy2.jpg");
}
```

but your first html has errors, you shouldn't declare a div outside the `body`

Not valid html

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MakeHappy.css" />
</head>
<div id="wink" class="imageSwap">
</div>
<body>
</body>
```

But in general your html and css has not good practises and inconsistent code. I never use id to style a element, only classes. Also keep your classes and ids lowercase like `some-class` instead of `SomeClass`. Also I think you can avoid to absolute position your navigation elements.